# Finding an Explicit Formula for Probability Given the Recursive Formula

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I am attempting to solve a problem asking for the formula to find a probability, $p(n)$, $n$ being 3, 4, 5,... I was able to determine that $p(3) = 1/4$  and the $p(n)$ given not $p(n-1)= \frac{n-2}{2(n-1)}$. From that, I can write the recursive formula: 
$$p(n) = p(n-1) + \frac{(1-p(n-1))(n-2)}{2(n-1)}$$
How can I turn this into an explicit formula for $p(n)$? Thanks.

Comment: It might help to note that your equation is equivalent to $$ 1-p(n)=\frac{n}{2(n-1)}(1-p(n-1)) $$

Comment: @robjohn, then $p(4)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $p(5) = \frac{11}{16}$. Probably the recursive formula is wrong

Comment: @dEmigOd: No other values for $p(n)$, other than $p(3)$, are given.  Why do you say the recursive formula is wrong?

Comment: @robjohn, what do you mean? that $p(3)$ is given, but $p(4)$ is something completely different? (I have just plugged $p(3)$ into the formula)

Comment: @dEmigOd: No, I am asking why you say that the recursive formula is wrong because it gives $p(4)=\frac12$ and $p(5)=\frac{11}{16}$? The question is to find a closed formula given the recursive formula. Using the form I give in my first comment, it is not too hard to get a closed formula for $p(n)$.

Comment: @robjohn, because probabilities, could not sum up to something more than $1$.

Comment: @dEmigOd: It was never stated that the $p(n)$ were probabilities of disjoint events. Here, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}p(n)=1$, so it seems that $p(n)$ is a cumulative probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post a solution by @robjohn

Let $t(n) = 1 - p(n)$, then we rewrite the equation as
$$ t(n) = \frac{n}{2(n-1)} t(n-1) = \frac{n}{2(n-1)}\cdot\frac{n-1}{2(n-2)}\cdot t(n-2)$$

you proceed to a generic step $k$
$$t(n) = \frac{n}{2(n-1)}\cdot\frac{n-1}{2(n-2)}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{n-k+1}{2(n-k)}\cdot t(n-k) = \frac{n}{2^k (n-k)}\cdot t(n-k)$$

Now, substitute $k = n-3$:
$$t(n) = \frac{n}{2^{n-3} \cdot 3}\cdot t(3) = \frac{n}{2^{n-3} \cdot 3} \cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$$

Therefore, $$p(n) = \frac{2^{n-1}-n}{2^{n-1}}.$$

Comment: Thank you. This is really helpful!